# Fixing AngularJS problems in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I've developed an app with AngularJS 1.2.13 (and JQuery 1.11.0) on Firefox.  It also works fine on Chrome.  Now for the hard part.  I've followed several advices for getting this to work on IE8.

When I load the page, I currently get the very useful "[object Error]" (and nothing else) in the JS console in the dev tools window.  The page shows the raw html as downloaded, so Angular basically was able to do nothing.

Here's the top of my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="DiagApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!--[if IE 8]><!--> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Even though I am NOT in quirks mode (in the dev tools window, the "Document mode" says "IE7 standards", not "Quirks Mode"), I still get the following:

```
  [$sce:iequirks] Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode.  You can fix this by adding the text <!doctype html> to the top of your HTML document.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce for more information.
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$sce/iequirks  angular.js, line 3689 character 19

So, I added the following to my config function in the module, which fixes this:

```
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
```

When I view the HTML in the "scripts" tab, it all appears to be colorized properly, which indicates to me it validated correctly (I had earlier discovered one typo in my HTML that caused this to not colorize correctly (a typo which Firefox and Chrome ignored)).

I set breakpoints to show that it's loading my modules, and also in the main controller.  That shows me it's loading the modules, but it never hits my main controller.  I tried setting some breakpoints in the angularjs code, but that led to all sorts of twisty passages with no obvious value.

I heard mention of some polyfills I should use for <=IE8, but I've only noticed mentions of polyfills for <=IE7.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't get Angular 1.2* to work on old IE. I've had to support old IE with our Angular site, and the best I could use was 1.1.5

Comment: Going back to 1.1.5 is another struggle.  I can't even figure out how to get my app working in Firefox with 1.1.5.  Now none of my ngRepeats are working.  No errors, it just doesn't do anything.  Comparing the docs for ngRepeat in 1.1.4 vs. 1.2.14, I don't see any obvious syntax differences.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with ng-repeat specifically then. Do you use any other libraries/plugins that might need to be downgraded to work with 1.1.5? Do you see any errors in your browser console? I use the same `<html>`/`<meta>` format as you, so that's not the problem. Did you follow everything else at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie ?

Comment: Well, some other frameworks in use are jquery and angularjs ui-bootstrap.  The latter works all the way back to AngularJS 1.0.8, so that's likely not an issue.  I tried downgrading the jquery to both 1.9.1 and 1.8.1 simply as a random check, and neither of those made a difference.  As I said earlier, there are no errors.  It just doesn't do anything.  I followed all of the relevant advice on the IE compatibility page.  I'm only targeting IE8, so I ignored the IE7-specific advice.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few factors to consider if you want support for your Angular app in IE8, namely:

- You'll need to polyfil your JSON to take care of stringify and parse
  functions not supported natively by the older IE versions
- You'll need to explicitly create any custom HTML element tags (custom
  HTML tags are not supported in IE8 or below)
- You'll need to get rid of any miscelanious 'doctype' nonsense You'll
  need to use the "ng-app" attribute (I note you've already taken care of this one)
- You'll need to create polyfills for some JS functions that IE 8
  doesn't support natively, for example 'forEach'

From the HTML I've seen (above), it looks like you need to modify your HTML header further for a start. In my case I have a shared '_Layout.cshtml' page where I do the following changes once and once only:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/iecss")
        <script src="~/Scripts/Libs/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script>
        document.createElement('ng-include');
        document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng-view');
        document.createElement('ng:include');
        document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng:view');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <script src="~/Scripts/Libs/json2.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script>
        document.createElement('my-editor');
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

When i have to support quirks mode i've found that once you've set `$sceProvider.enabled(false);` and added all the shims, you'll also need to polyfill `indexOf` and `filter`. Recently i've been using https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim which does the trick.